# Doctrine2 - how to soft delete

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have following requirement

I am working in symfony2, doctrine2

I have table - categories which is having column deleted (0/1).

I have another few tables more than one having ref id (foreign key) of categories table

for e.g.

Table1 
-id 
-categoriesid 
-description

Table2 
- id 
- categoriesid 
- name

and so on....

I want to achieve when I try to set deleted =1 of categories table then it should throw error if ref of that record is exist in either Table1, Table2

Need help to achieve above

Comment: Take a look at the softdeletable doctrine extension, it may help you do what you want: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md

Answer (score 0):

To add a check of your entity, that depend on another ones, you can use **event subscriber**.

You can read more about them in [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

There is also [examplary subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class).

Put your logic in it:

> I want to achieve when I try to set deleted =1 of categories table then it should throw error if ref of that record is exist in either Table1, Table2

Try `preUpdate` event. Change if needed.